# Trying to find a faster solution for Project Euler #14 in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I tried to write a solution for problem 14 of Project Euler. MY fastest - NOT the one below - ran in 58 seconds or so. The fastest I found using Google looked more or less like this:

```
%% ets:delete(collatz) (from shell) deletes the table.

-module(euler) .
-export([problem_14/1]) .

collatz(X) ->
  case ets:lookup(collatz, X) of
    [{X, Val}] -> Val ;
    []         -> case X rem 2 == 0 of
                    true  ->
                      ets:insert(collatz, {X, Val = 1+collatz(X div 2)} ) ,
                      Val ;
                    false ->
                      ets:insert(collatz, {X, Val = 1+collatz(3*X+1)} ) ,
                      Val
                  end
  end .

%% takes 10 seconds for N=1000000 on my netbook after "ets:delete(collatz)".
problem_14(N) ->
  case ets:info(collatz) of
    undefined ->
      ets:new(collatz, [public, named_table]) ,
      ets:insert(collatz,{1,1}) ;
    _         -> ok
  end ,
  lists:max([ {collatz(X), X} || X <- lists:seq(1,N) ]) .
```

But it still takes 10.5 seconds with a empty table. The fastest solution in C++ I found just takes 0.18 seconds which is 58 times faster. So I guess even if Erlang is not made for stuff like that, better code can be written. Does anybody perhaps know what I could try to gain some speed?

Comment: Though there's 1000000 integers, it is no need to calculate them all to 1. There are some "path" appear frequently. For example, 13 and 80 have most the same steps.

Comment: @halfelf, in code, which presented in question, `ets` table used for memorizing, so the identical parts of "paths" doesn't calculate twice.

Comment: Erlang uses arbitrary precision integers, doesn't it? If it has, using a native 64-bit integer type could give a big speedup. Another point, you're putting a lot of numbers `> 1000000` into the lookup table (1168611). Only 46675 of them are ever looked up again. It's probably faster to only memoise the values for `n <= 1000000` (but that depends on how the memoisation is implemented). Possibly memoising with a mutable array - if available - is also a win (it's a big win in Haskell). Last, try whether bitmasking and shifting instead of `rem 2` and `div 2` gives a speedup.

Comment: While reading the manual properly I found out that on every ets:insert objects are copied. So I guess this is the main bottleneck here.

Answer (score 1):

I've speed up your code a bit: specified ets as `ordered_set`, used bitwise operations and implemented tail-recursive function `max_size_index` instead of collecting all results to list, and after that iterating through it to find max value (as in our code).

```
-module(collatz).
-compile(export_all).

size(1, _) ->
        1;
size(N, Hashset) ->
        case ets:lookup(Hashset, N) of
                [{N, Size}] ->
                        Size;
                [] ->
                        Size  = 1 + size( next(N), Hashset ),
                        ets:insert(Hashset, {N, Size}),
                        Size
        end.

next(N) when N band 1 == 0 ->
        N bsr 1;
next(N) ->
        (N bsl 1)+N+1.

max_size_index(1, _Hashset, {Index, MaxSize}) ->
        {Index, MaxSize};
max_size_index(N, Hashset, {Index, MaxSize}) ->
        CurrSize = size(N, Hashset),
        case CurrSize > MaxSize of
                true ->
                        max_size_index(N-1, Hashset, {N, CurrSize});
                false ->
                        max_size_index(N-1, Hashset, {Index, MaxSize})
        end.

problem_14(N) ->
        Hashset = ets:new(collatz_count, [public, ordered_set]),
        max_size_index(N, Hashset, {1,1}).
```

Test in shell - your module `euler` and my module `collatz` ()

```
1> c(euler).
{ok,euler}
2> 
2> timer:tc(euler, problem_14, [1000000]). 
{4039838,{525,837799}}
3> 
3> c(collatz).
{ok,collatz}
4> 
4> timer:tc(collatz, problem_14, [1000000]). 
{2824109,{837799,525}}
```

And the last tip for speed up - large interval can be splitted into smaller, and spawn calculations for each small interval in parallel (on other nodes).

Comment: Your version takes 12 seconds here. But I guess since every call of ets:insert copies objects, ets is just not the way if you need millions of inserts in a second...

Answer (score 0):

In general, raw CPU-bound operation is not the strength of Erlang. The problem, as you note, is that data are copied to and from the ETS table. There is an advantage with a central ETS table which also locks: atomic updates. So you can easily get more cores to work on the problem if you want. You won't get near the speed of a C++ or C solution though.

The other problem you have for these kinds of problems is mutability. Erlang has an (almost) pure functional language in its (sequential) core. So you cannot hope to beat a C++ solution with an ephemeral hash table or an array into which it can store the million entries it operates on. You may try the `array` module, but I doubt it will be any faster.

Comment: For me Problem 14 is the first one I couldn't find a fast answer for so far. So I was more afraid that it is just my fault. (The solutions using an array I found are not faster btw.)